# i18n: How do I load translations for a language specified in the request?

Tags: localization

So I know how __, _e etc. work. They fetch the translations on the basis of the site language selected in the General settings. My challenge is slightly different: I want to provide the ability to specify the language dynamically, let's say in the request as a `lang` parameter. I want this `lang` parameter to be used to determine the translation not the site language. In the twentytwentythree theme (the theme I'm testing with but not limited to only this theme), all the static texts are loaded before the `template_redirect` or `template_include` hooks are called (and I can set the language in those hooks only) so it looks like this cannot be done.

Any idas?